# How to be able to import every file in a folder in google drive?

Tags: python, google-api, google-colaboratory

I read [this](https://buomsoo-kim.github.io/colab/2018/04/16/Importing-files-from-Google-Drive-in-Google-Colab.md/) article which was about how we can import files in a google drive to our google colab environment. For each file we go through these steps as the article says:

1 - Get a shareable link

2 - then we extract the id section of the link.

3 - after that we use this code to be able to import

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':"your_file_ID"})
downloaded.GetContentFile('your_file_name.csv')
```

So then I can write `import file.py`. I wanted to ask that is there any way that I could get the access to main folder and start importing like `from shared_file.subfolder.some_module import func1, class1`?

What I really need is to do authentication just once and avoid doing all the steps above for each file in a folder. Even automating above steps can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the folder is in your own Google Drive, it's easier. Otherwise, you can add that folder to your Google Drive first (it won't take your space quota).

Then you can mount it with

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('gdrive')
```

Now, you can access that folder, by changing the current directory.

```
import os
os.chdir("/content/gdrive/My Drive/that_folder")
```

Now you can import `your_library.py` easily, because it's in the current directory.

```
from your_library import *
```

Comment: that really helped a lot. The answer was concise and accurate. thanks a lot.